# use :after to put a box on an image - not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a gray bar across an image using css :after

When I try the below the image appears, but not the red box. If I replace the image with a p tag with the same class then it works as expected.

Why can't I see the red box on top of the image?

```
<div id="wrapper">
<img class="grayborder" src="mad-dogs-eyes.jpg" height="450" width="322" alt="two mad dogs " />
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}


img:after {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    top:100px;
    right:10px;
    z-index:1001;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img` elements are [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element), you cannot use `pseudo` elements with them, you will need to apply your `after` to the parent div `#wrapper`, or wrap the `img` in another element

> In CSS, a replaced element is an element whose representation is
>   outside the scope of CSS. These are kind of external objects whose
>   representation is independent of the CSS. Typical replaced elements
>   are `<img>`, `<object>`, `<video>` or form elements like `<textarea>` and
>   . Some elements, like `<audio>` or `<canvas>` are replaced elements
>   only in specific cases. Objects inserted using the CSS content
>   properties are anonymous replaced elements.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/p8bLm3y3/1/)

Comment: many thanks! I had not heard of 'replaced elements' and my searches turned up no answers. Now its working fine - so thanks again!